# getting error in case of table partitioning by LIST COLUMNS

Tags: mysql, database-partitioning

i have a table with below structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `orders_partition` (
  `Order_Id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `Category_Id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `Order_No` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `Student_Id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Country_Id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `Total_Refers` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Pages` float(5,1) NOT NULL,
  `Word_count` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Order_Type_Id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Reference_Style_Id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Payment_Mode_Id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Payment_Status_Id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Order_IP` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `Order_Amount` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `Order_Status_Id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Panic` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Url_Referal_Detail` text CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `publish_status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `L_Q_Reason_Id` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT 'NULL',
  `Transfer_Status` enum('NT','T','A') CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'A' COMMENT 'NT=>not transfer,T=>transfer,A=>allowed to transfer',
  `Visibility` enum('E','D') CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'E' COMMENT 'E=enabled, D=disabled',
  `Active_Date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `Active_Status` enum('A','DA') CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'A' COMMENT 'A=>Active,DA=>Deactive'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE `orders_partition`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`Order_Id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `Order_Id` (`Order_Id`),
  ADD KEY `Order_Status_Id` (`Order_Status_Id`),
  ADD KEY `Country_Id` (`Country_Id`)
```

Executing below partitioning Query

```
ALTER TABLE orders_partition
PARTITION BY LIST COLUMNS (Active_Status)
(
   PARTITION p01 VALUES IN ('A'),
PARTITION p02 VALUES IN ('DA')
 )
```

Getting below error

> 1659 - Field 'Active_Status' is of a not allowed type for this type of partitioning

I am tring to implement partitioning (LIST COLUMNS) in our mysql table and mysql version is 5.7

Comment: Hey, welcome to stack overflow, if you want to add code the next time, you can use the following syntax to have this grey tables: ``` your code ```

Comment: Thankyou for formatting my question. I will follow your instruction(``` your code ```) next time.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to partition on a flag; it is unlikely to provide any benefit.

MySQL's `PARTITIONing` has a number of limitations; you ran into the restriction on what datatypes can be partitioned on -- The list does not include `ENUM`.

If you had gotten past that, the next error would be the need to include the "partition key" in every unique key (including the primary key).

Meanwhile, `UNIQUE(Order_id)` is redundant with `PRIMARY KEY(Order_id)`.  A PK is (by MySQL's definition) a key and unique.